# SQLite does not have a DATE datatype? How can I workaround this?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sqlite

SQLite doesn't have a data type for dates.

I was wondering if it's enough to make string comparisons between date strings like `Y-m-d H:i:s` (the standard sql datetime format).

For example `...WHERE date < NOW()...`. would this fail in certain situations?

Comment: http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html

Comment: but i cant use those if I want my query to be compatible with mysql too

Comment: I'm sorry. I didn't get what was the problem. I would just use Unix Timestamp.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can store dates in SQLite with the following data types:

- **TEXT** as ISO8601 strings ("YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS").
- **REAL** as Julian day numbers, the number of days since noon in Greenwich on November 24, 4714 B.C. according to the proleptic Gregorian calendar.
- **INTEGER** as Unix Time, the number of seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC.

You can then convert these fake dates using the functions listed [here](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html).

Now, you also mentioned function `NOW()` and that won't work in SQLite. That's for MySQL. This will show you SQLite syntax to use:

```
sqlite> select date('now');
2012-02-12
sqlite> select date('now') = date('2012-02-12');
1
sqlite> select date('now') = date('2012-02-11');
0
```

So, it is highly recommended for you to use this functions and, on the other side, make sure you don't use `NOW()`.

Comment: ten years later, it is still ridiculous that sqlite doesn't have proper datetime support.

Answer (score 3):

Quoted From Roger

> SQLite doesn't have dedicated [datetime types](http://sqlite.org/datatype3.html), but does have a [few
>   datetime functions](http://sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html). Follow the string representation formats (actually
>   only formats 1-10) understood by those functions (storing the value as
>   a string) and then you can use them, plus lexicographical comparison
>   on the strings will match datetime comparison (as long as you don't
>   try to compare dates to times or datetimes to times, which doesn't
>   make a whole lot of sense anyway).
>
> Depending on which language you use, you can even get [automatic
>   conversion](http://docs.python.org/library/sqlite3.html#default-adapters-and-converters). (Which doesn't apply to comparisons in SQL statements like
>   the example, but will make your life easier.)

Answer (score 2):

Personally I like using unsigned INT and unix timestamps for dates. It is very easy and efficient to compare dates as integers, and PHP has numerous functions for making these dates human readable.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 2):

Using `now()` won't work because SQLite doesn't know what the means. SQLite does, however, know what `current_timestamp` means and [that has the desired format](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html):

> The format for CURRENT_TIMESTAMP is "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS".

In MySQL, `current_timestamp` is a synonym for [`now()` and that also has the desired format](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now):

> Returns the current date and time as a value in `'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS'`.

So they both use [ISO-8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO-8601) timestamp formats and just about any database will be able to convert between ISO-8601 strings to and timestamps quite easily so that is a good and portable choice.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty certain it would fail in certain situations.
A faster method would be storing time() values (or mktime()) and generating queries based on time().

This would also work with MySQL.